# Difference Between HEAD and HEAD:HEAD

Tags: git, fetch, repository, head, git-fetch

What is the difference between `HEAD` and `HEAD:HEAD` notation in git commands e.g.:

```bash
git fetch origin HEAD:HEAD
```

I can even understand what `git fetch origin HEAD` does, however, not using the other notation.

I would be grateful for any kind of help or advice.

Answer (score 2):

The notation "HEAD:HEAD" in Git commands like "git fetch origin HEAD:HEAD" may look a bit confusing, but it is essentially a shorthand for a common operation. Let me break it down for you:

HEAD (without the colon):

- When you use HEAD without a colon in a Git command, it typically refers to the currently checked out commit in your local repository. In other words, it points to the commit that your working directory and the "HEAD" branch are currently at.

HEAD:HEAD (with the colon):

- In the context of a fetch operation, such as "git fetch origin HEAD:HEAD," the "HEAD:HEAD" notation is specifying a source and destination reference for the fetch operation. In this notation:
  -The part before the colon represents the source, which is typically a reference to a commit or a branch in the remote repository (in this case, "origin").
  -The part after the colon represents the destination, which is typically a reference in your local repository.

When you use "git fetch origin HEAD:HEAD," it is effectively saying: "Fetch the commit that 'HEAD' in the 'origin' remote repository is pointing to and update the local 'HEAD' to that same commit."

Comment: I thought I understood how it works with your explanation: if I run `git fetch origin HEAD:HEAD` I would be saying to "fetch the data from the HEAD pointer in origin and update it with what in my local repository the HEAD points to"...

Comment: ... This is what I understood and I'm actually confused, does this mean that when I fetch the origin/HEAD information, I will move my local HEAD pointer to the newest fetched commit? I was thinking that this was what would happen but when executing the command I ended up with a new branch created which is literally called "HEAD" which was in the most recent commit (which was downloaded), but my HEAD was not moved, continues to point to main in the old commit.